# Starting from Gauss's law, prove that the Electrostatic potential satisfies Poisson's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

If we start from differential form of Gauss Law and take out divergence of E , I am getting it to be zero. How's is it possible? [image: Can you tell where I am going wrong here?]

So how do I proceed further in order to prove that Electrostatic potential satisfies Gauss's Law? 
Do I need to derive Poisson's equation for this proof?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question. Please don't post images of equations. This breaks search functionality and adaptive technology for the blind.

Comment: Okay! I am new here, will definitely keep in mind next time. Thank you for letting me know! Also how do I write such equations here? Does it support latex?

Comment: yes, you can use a subset of latex (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation))

Answer (score 1):

If you start from the differential form of the Gauss law then you are essentially already there. We know that in electrostatics $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = 0$, meaning that the electric field can be written as minus the gradient of a function $V$, that is, $\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla} V$. The divergence of the field thus can be written as

$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \vec{\nabla} \cdot (-\vec{\nabla} V) = - \nabla^2V
$$

which means that the local form of Gauss's law becomes

$$
\nabla^2V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$

which is the Poisson's equation for electrostatics.

Comment: But how do we know that V here is the Electrostatic potential? How can we show that? Electric field can be expressed as a gradient of a scalar but how to show that this scalar is electric potential?

Comment: Also, can you tell me why am I getting divergence of E to be zero here?

Comment: @NashitaRahman You are getting $0$ because you are looking at the divergence at all locations except $r=0$ where the point charge is actually located

Comment: So how do I calculate the divergence of E in case of a point charge?

Comment: @NashitaRahman There is no such a thing as a "point charge": single points in space cannot have a finite charge, which is why we use the concept of charge density. The use of point charges in electrostatics is justified by applying Gauss law to a spherically-symmetric charge density and noting that the resulting electric field is the same as the one generated by a point charge

Comment: @Ir1985 Oh I see! Thank you! But then why is the divergence coming out to be zero? Is it because the charge density is uniformly distributed ?

Comment: Take into account that $\nabla \cdot  \left[ \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}  \right] \, = \, 4 \pi \, \delta\left(\vec{\mathbf{x}}\right) \, 
 = \, \frac{1}{r^2} \, \delta(r) \,$.